# React - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/andreadavide/Documents/testAssoDeploy/node_modules/basic-ftp/dist'

Tags: reactjs, module, ftp, fs

I'm struggling with this error and I've already tried many ways but unfortunately I'm not able to solve the problem.

When I install any kind of FTP npm I receive this error. I've installed "basic-ftp" this time.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/andreadavide/Documents/testAssoDeploy/node_modules/basic-ftp/dist`
```

I tried in several ways, also adding to the root of package.json.

```
  "browser": {
  "fs": false,
  "path": false,
  "os": false
}
```

but still not working.
What I need to do is to work with FTP and fetch data from ftp web server, so I would need a npm for that. All the npm give me this error.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `fs` is a NodeJS standard library to access file system. It is not available in the browser, you may need to implement your FTP access server-side.

Comment: Ok thanks! Sorry but I'm a beginner. What do you mean? I would like to fetch data from a FTP directory and map it in the client side.

Comment: If you think what you're trying to do in your browser - you want to download the file from FTP server and do something with client-side. Execution environment (your browser) does not allow you to directly access file system to store the files you've downloaded from this FTP server. What I suggest you to do is to implement your own backend (for instance, implemented in NodeJS, having access to file system) where you'll interact with FTP.